# Schema.org's WebApplication: for web applications or references to web application?

Tags: web-applications, schema.org

Assuming one offers an online service on a page using HTML5 + JavavaScript. Technically speaking, it can be considered as a web application.

Is the [`WebApplication` type](http://schema.org/WebApplication) appropriate for this page or should it only be used for references to web applications (i.e., reviews etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, a [web application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application) is:

> Any application that uses a web browser as a client. The term may also
>   mean a computer software application that is coded in a
>   browser-supported programming language (such as JavaScript, combined
>   with a browser-rendered markup language like HTML) and reliant on a
>   common web browser to render the application executable.

Since this matches the description of your web application, I don't see why you couldn't use Schema.org's [WebApplication](http://schema.org/WebApplication) for web applications.

According to Google's docs on [rich snippets for software applications](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1645432?hl=en), you should likely include the `browsers` property to describe the browser requirements, for example: "Browser required with HTML5 and JavavaScript support".